# Android WorkManager PeriodicWorkRequest execution issue

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have an app that downloads data from an online database. It uses PeriodicWorkRequest and it doesn't work as expected. I use WorkManager 2.3.0.

There is my WorkManager settings

```
public class ReminderUtil {
public static final String ARTICLE_WORK_TAG = "article_work";

public static void scheduleReminder(Context context) {

    PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest
            .Builder(ArticleWorker.class, 120, MINUTES, 10, MINUTES)
            .setInitialDelay(1, MINUTES)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(ARTICLE_WORK_TAG,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
}
```

Worker class

```
public class ArticleWorker extends Worker {

private Context mContext;

public ArticleWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    mContext = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    //downloading new article date list
    List<ArticleLight> recentArticleLightList = QueryUtils.getArticlesLight(ArticleUtils.articleUrl);
    //sorting by Date
    Collections.sort(recentArticleLightList, (o1, o2) -> o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate()));
    Date newestDate = recentArticleLightList.get(0).getDate();
    String articleText = recentArticleLightList.get(0).getTitle();
    //compare newestDate with last saved sate
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long savedDateLong = prefs.getLong("date", 0);
    savedDateLong = savedDateLong - 604800000;//todo this is a notification test
    Date savedDate = new Date(savedDateLong);
    Log.i("myTAG", "WORKER");
    if (newestDate.compareTo(savedDate) > 0) {
        //we have new article!
        NotificationUtil.createNotification(mContext, articleText);
        Log.i("myTAG", "NOTIFICATION");
    }

    return Result.success();
}
```

}

And there is my log

```
2020-02-02 15:34:39.506 29571-7035/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: WORKER
2020-02-02 15:34:39.521 29571-7035/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: NOTIFICATION
2020-02-02 15:50:00.983 29571-31372/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: WORKER
2020-02-02 15:50:00.998 29571-31372/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: NOTIFICATION
2020-02-02 16:05:01.981 29571-337/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: WORKER
2020-02-02 16:05:01.995 29571-337/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: NOTIFICATION
2020-02-02 16:20:32.641 29571-3899/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: WORKER
2020-02-02 16:20:32.710 29571-3899/com.g84.spacenewstheguardian I/myTAG: NOTIFICATION
```

As you can see the worker should run every 120 minutes with 10 minutes flexi time but it runs approximately every 16 minutes.

**EDIT:**

My goal is create a daily request at a specific time. So I tried to change the PeriodicWorkRequest to OneTimeWorkRequest.
When app is installed, it triggers the OneTimeWorkRequest with calculated initialDelay to a required hour. When the Worker is triggered, it sets new OneTimeWorkRequest (again with calculated initialDelay).
So far it works as I require, but still testing.

```
public class ReminderUtil {

    public static final String ARTICLE_WORK_TAG = "article_work";
    private static final int dayInMill = 86400000;
    private static final int minDelay = 960000;//16 min - Min interval for WorkManager

   public static void scheduleReminder2(Context context) {

        if(!isWorkScheduled2(context)) { // check if my work is not already scheduled
            scheduleWork2(context); // schedule my work
        }
    }

    public static void scheduleWork2(Context context) {

        OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder myBuilder =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ArticleWorker.class)
                        .setInitialDelay(calculateDelay(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .addTag(ARTICLE_WORK_TAG)
                        .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build());

        OneTimeWorkRequest myRequest = myBuilder.build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueue(myRequest);
    }

private static boolean isWorkScheduled2(Context context) {
        WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
        ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance.getWorkInfosByTag(ReminderUtil.ARTICLE_WORK_TAG);
        try {
            boolean running = false;
            List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = statuses.get();
            for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
                WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
                running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
            }
            return running;
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static long calculateDelay() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar future = Calendar.getInstance();
        // When to run the job
        int hourOfTheDay = 8;
        future.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay);
        future.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        future.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long diff = future.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

        if (diff > minDelay) {
            return diff;
        }
        else
            return diff + dayInMill;
    }
}
```

And Worker class

```
public class ArticleWorker extends Worker {

    private Context mContext;

    public ArticleWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        //downloading new article date list
        List<ArticleLight> recentArticleLightList = QueryUtils.getArticlesLight(ArticleUtils.articleUrl);
        //sorting by Date
        Collections.sort(recentArticleLightList, (o1, o2) -> o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate()));
        Date newestDate = recentArticleLightList.get(0).getDate();
        String articleText = recentArticleLightList.get(0).getTitle();
        //compare newestDate with last saved sate
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        long savedDateLong = prefs.getLong("date", 0);
        savedDateLong = savedDateLong - 604800000;//todo this is a notification test
        Date savedDate = new Date(savedDateLong);
        Log.i("myTAG", "WORKER");
        if (newestDate.compareTo(savedDate) > 0) {
            //we have new article!
            NotificationUtil.createNotification(mContext, articleText);
            Log.i("myTAG", "NOTIFICATION");
        }

        ReminderUtil.scheduleWork2(mContext);//todo test of oneTime Work

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing make sure your PeriodicWorkRequest is not created multiple times and you can check with WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork method.

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder myWorkBuilder =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ArticleWorker.class, 120, MINUTES, 10, 
    MINUTES);

 PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = myWorkBuilder.build();
 WorkManager.getInstance()
.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("jobTag", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, myWork);
```

This method allows you to enqueue a uniquely-named PeriodicWorkRequest, where only one PeriodicWorkRequest of a particular name can be active at a time. For example, you may only want one sync operation to be active. If there is one pending, you can choose to let it run or replace it with your new work.

Comment: You can start as many `PeriodicWorkRequest` as you want.  Just use **ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE**